# Inserting new record in between the list of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to insert a record between the records which are already in the table. There are over 40000 records, and I would like to place this new record at 19th place. How may I do so?

Let's consider an example with 5 records:

Table data:

```
CREATE TABLE enum
  (identifier  VARCHAR2(64),
   code VARCHAR2(512),
   data VARCHAR2(4000))
/
INSERT ALL 
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, L6', 'Halli, L6')
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, L7', 'Halli, L7')
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, L8', 'Halli, L8')
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, L9', 'Halli, L9')
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, P6', 'Halli, P6')
INTO enum VALUES ('HR_B_A', 'Halli, P7', 'Halli, P7')
select * from dual
/
```

So when we check the table, we get:

```
SELECT * FROM enum

IDENTIFIER     CODE         DATA
----------   ---------    ---------
HR_B_A       Halli, L6    Halli, L6
HR_B_A       Halli, L7    Halli, L7
HR_B_A       Halli, L8    Halli, L8
HR_B_A       Halli, L9    Halli, L9
HR_B_A       Halli, P6    Halli, P6
HR_B_A       Halli, P7    Halli, P7
```

What I would like to have when I run the select query:

```
SELECT * from enum

IDENTIFIER     CODE         DATA
    ----------   ---------    ---------
    HR_B_A       Halli, L6    Halli, L6
    HR_B_A       Halli, L7    Halli, L7
    HR_B_A       Halli, L8    Halli, L8
    HR_B_A       Halli, L9    Halli, L9
    HR_B_A       Halli, L10   Halli, L10
    HR_B_A       Halli, P6    Halli, P6
    HR_B_A       Halli, P7    Halli, P7
```

The only way I can think of is transfer the data till L9 line in a table (e.g enum_temp), insert L10 line and then transfer the remaining data in that table. But I can't seem to figure out the syntax of the query.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Rows in a relational database are not sorted**

There is no way you can ensure any desired ordering unless you use an `ORDER BY` expression in your SELECT.

As you are mixing several types of "information" in your values, you will need to use something like this:

```
select *
from enum
order by regexp_replace(code, '[0-9]', ''), 
         to_number(regexp_replace(code, '[^0-9]', ''))
```

The first order by expression orders by the part of the code that does not contain numbers. That way all `Halli, L` values are sorted together. The second order by expression then sorts by the numeric value of the code (stripping of all non-numeric characters).

Answer (score 3):

There is not implicit order in the way records are stored in a table. You can use sorting in your queries for viewing your list in the desired order.

What you can do is add a `POSITION` column (of type `NUMBER`) which indicates the position of the record in the list. Then if you want to insert a record to the nth position of the list do :

```
UPDATE enum SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= <desired nth position> 
INSERT INTO enum VALUES(<desired nth position>, ....)
```

to view the list in order do :

```
SELECT * FROM enum ORDER BY position ASC
```

**EDIT :**  And add an index on the POSITION column (type b-tree index) for making your queries faster